# Stack Trace Detection in an Eclipse Editor

Tags: eclipse

I have a plain text file, and I want to be able to open it in an Eclipse editor and have Eclipse recognize that the file contains some (normally formatted) Java stack traces.

In particular, I'd like to be able to click on the lines in these stack traces and have Eclipse "jump" to the correct location in my source code--the way it does if I click on the stack traces in the stdout Console, or do an "Open Declaration" on a token in my java source code.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I've looked into using the Java Stack Trace Console, but a) it doesn't seem to recognize any of my stack traces, and b) it requires me to cut and paste from the editor.  It would be cooler if the Eclipse editor itself somehow recognized stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

Do be able to click, just paste the text to the Console view. Usually you can paste in any console window, but if you Console does not allow you to do this, switch it to "Java Stack Trace Console" and paste there.

See http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/console/ref-stacktrace_console.htm