# Customize Eclipse's java stack trace console formatter

Tags: eclipse, formatting, stack-trace

Eclipse has a stack trace console where you can paste in any stack trace, and it'll try to make the MyClass:143 references clickable. There's a [format function](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/console/ref-format_action.htm) that does this for you, but the stack traces I get from my app's log files are big single lines with &s separating each trace item.

Is there a way to customize the format function so it'll also do a global replace? In my case I want to do `s/&/\n/`

The [only other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143923/stack-trace-detection-in-an-eclipse-editor) I've found just talks about using this console, not modifying the format function.

Comment: help.eclipse.org seems to be crashing (OOM errors) so here's the google cache of the page I linked: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EUv-7qTDKBIJ:help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/console/ref-format_action.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen anything in the preferences for this, also from looking at the code in Eclipse this area doesn't seem particularly extensible.

I think you'd have to contribute your own action to the console, however you'd have to write a bit of code...
Take a look at FormatStackTraceActionDelegate - the result of running this action eventually calls:
private String format(String trace) in JavaStackTraceConsole
That's really where you want to hook in right?

If it were me, and something I was doing all the time I'd write the action, however it may be a lot of work for the reward.

Comment: any idea for the debugger formatter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648576/how-to-configure-the-detail-formatter-for-stacktraceelement-java-array-in-ecli